# Magento customize header disposition

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I'm really new to Magento, and i'm having some trouble with my header. 
There is an image with my header actually : https://i.stack.imgur.com/POwwX.jpg

As you can see, next to my title RENNESBOUTIQUES.com i have a shopping icon and then an input to search for some product in my shop.

But i can't find where is defined the disposition of the header in the magento code. On the default layout of the blank theme there is only this :

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container">
<container name="header.panel.wrapper" htmlClass="panel wrapper" htmlTag="div" before="-">
    <container name="header.panel" label="Page Header Panel" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="panel header">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="skip_to_content" template="Magento_Theme::html/skip.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="target" xsi:type="string">contentarea</argument>
                <argument name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Skip to Content</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="switch/languages.phtml"/>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="top.links">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </container>
</container>
<container name="header-wrapper" label="Page Header" as="header-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header content row">
    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo" name="logo">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">189</argument>
            <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">64</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</container>
```

I have found the module folders for twice icon and search input but now I wan't that icon to be displayed at the right of my search input.

If anyone have an idea, hurry to hear about it.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: have you tried to move? like `<move element="minicart" destination='header-container' after='search'>` it is a just example you can do similar like this as per your requirement

Comment: Yes but i didn't know what is the name of the block but with  @impunkj response, i found it and use this ! It's working like a charm now. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to template path hints to one check which file is coming to header.
PLease follow,

Stores > Configuration > Click to Advanced > Developer > Switch to store main website.
Than 
Enabled Template Path Hints for to YES.
Add Block Names to Hints to Yes

[image]

Comment: Thanks mate, this is what i was looking. I found the name of the block in the default.xml folder. That's not the complete response, but you helped me a lot.